# How to build menu "views" and make it loop in CodeIgniter Template Parser?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, templates, foreach

My database:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | slug  | text  |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | link1 | text1 |
| 2  | link2 | text2 |
| 3  | link3 | text3 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

My array (queried from database):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [slug] => link1
            [text] => text1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [slug] => link2
            [text] => text2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [slug] => link3
            [text] => text3
        )
```

I want to write my view like this but I can't get it to work in a loop. (I sent the array for parsing already).

```
<ul>
{xxxxx}
    <li><a href="{slug}">{text}</a></li>
{/xxxxx}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your array in a variable like:

```
$data['blogs'] = $my_result_array_from_model;
```

Send the data to view:

```
$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

Then, in your view,

```
<ul>
    {blogs}
        <li><a href="{slug}">{text}</a></li>
    {/blogs}
</ul>
```

For reference: Check out [Official CI Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html#parsing-templates)

Comment: I have my array already. I also sent the data to view already. You can see my original questions. I shown you the data for my arrays but I'm stuck in the views part. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share how are you sending the data to view via parser?

Comment: First, I set the data from my database to this string as array `$this->subnav = $this->db->get('subnav')->result_array();` (you can see the `print_r();` of my array in my question) then I just send it for parsing... `$this->parser->parse('mytemplatefilehere', $this->subnav);` it's actually in multidimensional array maybe thats why I cant get it to work?

Comment: That's the part... As mentioned in the first line of my answer, wrap your subnav in any php variable, say `$data`
Then pass that $data like this: `$this->parser->parse('mytemplatefilehere', $data);`

Comment: Try like this: `$data['subnav'] = $this->subnav;` then send it to the parser: `$this->parser->parse('mytemplatefilehere', $data);`. To use them in your view, type like this: `<ul>
    {subnav}
        <li><a href="{slug}">{text}</a></li>
    {/subnav}
</ul>`

Comment: Hey, thanks man! I got it working already. I finally got it after I do the "wrapping" thing... I'm accepting this as the answer...

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this helps you**

```
     $data['blog_entries'] = [
                              '0' => ['id' => 1,'slug' => 'link1','text' => 'text1'],
                              '1' => ['id' => 2,'slug' => 'link2','text' => 'text2'],
                              '2' => ['id' => 3,'slug' => 'link3','text' => 'text3']
                            ];


    $this->parser->parse('blog_templates', $data);
```

**In your view :**

```
 <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    // this is the array to iterate like this
   {blog_entries}
            <h5>{id}</h5>
            <p>{slug}</p>
            <p>{text}</p>
    {/blog_entries}

    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code you’ll notice a pair of variables: {blog_entries} data… {/blog_entries}. In a case like this, the entire chunk of data between these pairs would be repeated multiple times, corresponding to the number of rows in the “blog_entries” element of the parameters array.

**Result in view :**

```
            <h5>1</h5>
            <p>link1</p>
            <p>text1</p>

            <h5>2</h5>
            <p>link2</p>
            <p>text2</p>

            <h5>3</h5>
            <p>link3</p>
            <p>text3</p>
```

If your “pair” data is coming from a database result, which is already a multi-dimensional array, you can simply use the database `result_array`() method:

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM blog");

  $data = array(
    'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
    'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
    'blog_entries' => $query->result_array()
  );

  $this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

For More : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html